# Google Web Authorization on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, google-api, youtube-api

Hi i am using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker to authorize user,
below of my code ..

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = Server.MapPath("/");
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                    , new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                    ).Result;
            }
```

This code works well on ASP.Net Developement Server, its redirect user to google page for request for permission.
but when i host application on IIS its does not works. i set full psermission to iis_user and iuser. i am not sure what other things i need to do on IIS.

Thanks

Comment: define doesn't work.   Are you getting an error message?

Comment: it does not give error message.

Comment: then how do you know its not working did you check credPath to see if the user credentials exists?